# Download file from node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, meteor, save

In my metor/react application i have server method which creates protected zip file.

```
var image = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
var text = new Buffer(data);
var user_data = Meteor.user()._id;

mz.append(`${user_data}/data.json`, text, {
    password: password
});

mz.append(`${user_data}/national-id${path.extname(fileName)}`, image, {
    password: password
});

fs.writeFileSync(`${dir}/Cryptopass.zip`, new Buffer(mz.zip()));
```

Now how can I send it to client?

Answer (score 1):

This should be straightforward using Express:

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.route("/downloadzip").get(function(req,res){

    var mz = new Minizip();
    var image = fs.readFileSync(filePath);

    var text = new Buffer(data);
    var user_data = Meteor.user()._id;

    mz.append(`${user_data}/data.json`, text, {password: password});
    mz.append(`${user_data}/national-id${path.extname(fileName)}`, image, {password: password});

    res.type('zip').send(new Buffer(mz.zip()));
})

app.listen(8081);
```

To test this route using curl:

```
curl http://localhost:8081/downloadImage > test.zip
```